# Charles proxy не видит пакеты от мобильных устройств, т.к. не удается открыть chls.pro/ssl или http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl

Tags: android, ios, proxy, charles

1. установила charles, установила сертификаты
2. включила все настройки (enable ssl proxying, enable transparent HTTP proxing)
3. подключила ноутбук и телефон (проверяла на 5 девайсах - android/ios)
   к одной сеть wi-fi
4. в настройках сети на телефоне указала прокси- вручную, адрес = ip pc, port = 8888
5. открываю chls.pro/ssl или http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl - страницы не открываются
6. в самом charles не появляется окошко, что с такого девайса пытаются подключиться - разрешить или отклонить
7. попробовала в access control settings добавить вручную ip девайса с маской /24 и без

Ранее, чарльз работал с этими девайсами нормально. Но в какой-то момент перестал. Попробовала переустановить сертификат. Попробовала переустановить программу, удалив полностью все данные после uninstall.
На этой же машине через fiddler все работает нормально.
На другой машине чарльз с этими девайсами тоже работает. 
Помогите разобраться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: версия 4.2.1 30дневная

Comment: меняли роутер на ксяомишный, в котором используется режим "Двухчастотный Wi-Fi в одном" ?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, актуально ли Вам еще найти ответ, но в подобной ситуации помогло добавление разрешений для доступа в файрволе виндовс. После этого логи пошли нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

По указанному выше пути, надо поставить галочку напротив Charles Proxy Debugging[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если запросы через wifi не попадают в Charles - то можно завернуть трафик через USB с помощью adb (источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77634616/8705119):

1. Подключить смартфон к компьютеру и убедиться, что он виден в выводе

   ```
   adb devices
   ```

(запускать в терминале Android Studio)

2. В качестве ip адреса прокси на смартфоне указать 127.0.0.1 и порт 8080:

   ```
   adb shell settings put global http_proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
   ```

(вместо этого можно указать прокси-сервер в настройках wifi сети, но это долго и неудобно).

3. Перенаправить трафик с порта 8080 на смартфоне на порт 8888 на хосте:

   ```
   adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8888
   ```

После этого запросы будут идти через Charles.

4. после тестирования сбросить настройки:

   ```
   adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0
   adb reverse --remove-all
   ```

Посмотреть список reverse-ов (должен быть пустым):

```
adb reverse --list
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin добавил описание